# HTML with VBSscript write to table

Tags: html, vbscript

I would like to click a button and have a VBScript called to write to a table's lower half

eg:

```
--------
|Top
|-------
|bottom (vbscript writes to here)
--------
```

Is this possible? And how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Any reason you can't use Javascript? Is this an old ASP page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.document.getElementById("tablerow1").innerHTML = "Stuff"

Answer (score 1):

Generating HTML on-the-fly:
http://www.suite101.com/article.cfm/vb_script/62941

Comment: That was very close to what I was looking for.. But i found the solution. Thanks though.

Comment: If it was useful in anyway or could help someone else, don't forget that you can vote it up =)